# Specify icon size as a function of font size

Tags: android, fonts, accessibility

The app design that I'm implementing requires icon sizes to be a function of font size. The height of the icon should roughly match the height of the font.

It appears to be possible to specify any view size in sp.

Google has decreed that layout sizes [should not be specified in sp](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) but is there anything to stop me specifying an `ImageView` size in sp? It appears that nobody else is doing this and I'm worried about falling into unforeseen traps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the align options to size the icon

`android:layout_alignTop="@+id/your_font_view"`
`android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/your_font_view"`

and set `android:scaleType` to the appropriate value.

It would probably be best to be in a `RelativeLayout` as well

From [android dev site](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

"A dp is a density-independent pixel that corresponds to the physical size of a pixel at 160 dpi. An sp is the same base unit, but is scaled by the user's preferred text size (it’s a scale-independent pixel), so you should use this measurement unit when defining text size (but never for layout sizes)."

Comment: That could be a a workaround. Is there any reason not to use sp to specify the size of the ```ImageView```?

Comment: An ```ImageView```is not a layout as far as I am aware.

Comment: As far as I know `sp` is only for fonts, I think 'layout' in the quoted text is referring to layouts in a more general sense and not specifically to Layout views.

Comment: This is by far the best way to go. The icon size will scale with the text, and it avoids hacky solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can safely specify the ImageView size in sp. This is not recommended for layouts because they typically scale to fit their content and specifying their size in sp would a) be unnecessary and b) probably look bad.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Happy it's safe to set the ImageView size in sp. The motivation for specifying icon sizes in sp is based on the premise that that people who choose a larger text size are not going to be able see small icons. The designer wants the icon height to match the font height. In my option, the layout looks good, both for large and small text sizes.

Comment: That's a great reason to use sp. Glad to hear you're considering low-vision use cases!